# Azure sql data sync Agent 2 won't install

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, azure, synchronization

i'm having some issues on the installation of Microsoft SQL Data Sync Agent 2.

it shows a message telling me to install SQLSysClrTypes.msi and SharedManagementObjects.msi

[image]

even after installing those two requirements it keeps showing this message, it worked in another pc but in this one is not.

what should i do?

(pc is running windows 7 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just installed a fresh windows and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you have downloaded the x86 version of both prerequisites.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239643&clcid=0x409

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239658&clcid=0x409

.NET Framework 4.5 is required also.